# JPA JDBC to choose db credentials depending on url

Tags: jpa, jdbc

I have an application which is implemented using JPA. I want to establish db connection depending on the url type by the user i.e the url will decide the db credentials. I dont want to add anything in web.xml. I want to use orm.xml and persistence.xml. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Where do your authentication data comes from, if not from the context.xml/web.xml. Do you have multiple persistence.xml or...?

Comment: As you are talking about `web.xml` - I would guess that you are in an web application (JPA can be used in other containers as well). What do yo mean by _user_? You can for example use a _data source_ which is defined in your server configuration (e.g. `standalone.xml` in JBoss). In that case the user is the server administrator.